# Thread safety with Dictionary<int,int> in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, collections, thread-safety

I have this function:

```
static Dictionary<int, int> KeyValueDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
static void IncreaseValue(int keyId, int adjustment)
{
    if (!KeyValueDictionary.ContainsKey(keyId))
    {
        KeyValueDictionary.Add(keyId, 0);
    }
    KeyValueDictionary[keyId] += adjustment;
}
```

Which I would have thought would not be thread safe. However, so far in testing it I have not seen any exceptions when calling it from multiple threads at the same time.

My questions: Is it thread safe or have I just been lucky so far? If it is thread safe then why?

Comment: As Herb Sutter said (from memory): "What is the typical behavior of a race condition when we commit one? It slips through the unit tests & system tests. We have our release party. Then we get a call from our most important customer reporting non-deterministic crashes."

Comment: @FuleSnabel: lol, good one.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> However, so far in testing it I have not seen any exceptions when calling it from multiple threads at the same time.
>
> Is it thread safe or have I just been lucky so far? If it is thread safe then why?

You're getting lucky. These types of bugs with threads are so easy to make because testing can you give you a false sense of security that you did things correctly.

It turns out that `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is not thread-safe when you have multiple writers. The documentation explicitly states:

> A `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In the rare case where an enumeration contends with write accesses, the collection must be locked during the entire enumeration. **To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization.**

Alternatively, use [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx). However, you still must write correct code (see note below).

In addition to the lack of thread-safety with `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` which you've been lucky to avoid, your code is dangerously flawed. Here's how you can get a bug with your code:

```
static void IncreaseValue(int keyId, int adjustment) {
    if (!KeyValueDictionary.ContainsKey(keyId)) {
        // A
        KeyValueDictionary.Add(keyId, 0);
    }
    KeyValueDictionary[keyId] += adjustment;
}
```

1. Dictionary is empty.
2. Thread 1 enters the method with `keyId = 17`. As the Dictionary is empty, the conditional in the `if` returns `true` and thread 1 reaches the line of code marked `A`.
3. Thread 1 is paused and thread 2 enters the method with `keyId = 17`. As the Dictionary is empty, the conditional in the `if` returns `true` and thread 2 reaches the line of code marked `A`.
4. Thread 2 is paused and thread 1 resumes. Now thread 1 adds `(17, 0)` to the dictionary.
5. Thread 1 is paused and now thread 2 resumes. Now thread 2 tries to add `(17, 0)` to the dictionary. An exception is thrown because of a key violation.

There are other scenarios in which an exception can occur. For example, thread 1 could be paused while loading the value of `KeyValueDictionary[keyId]` (say it loads `keyId = 17`, and obtains the value `42`), thread 2 could come in and modify the value (say it loads `keyId = 17`, adds the adjustment `27`), and now thread 1 resumes and adds its adjustment to the value it loaded (in particular, it doesn't see the modification that thread 2 made to the value associated with `keyId = 17`!).

**Note that even using a `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` could lead to the above bugs! Your code is NOT safe for reasons not related to the thread-safety or lack thereof for `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`**.

To get your code to be thread-safe with a concurrent dictionary, you'll have to say:

```
KeyValueDictionary.AddOrUpdate(keyId, adjustment, (key, value) => value + adjustment);
```

Here we are using [`ConcurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378665.aspx).

Comment: +1: Good answer, thanks for putting in the effort. Especially enjoyed the bit where you explored why a "thread-safe" collection still allows for "thread-unsafe" code.

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort putting together that answer. My original solution had a lock around the entire content of the solution because I was not aware of ConcurrentDictionary which is a far more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

It's not thread safe, but does not check and so probably doesn't notice silent corruption.

It will appear to be thread safe for a long time because only when it needs to rehash() does it have even a chance of exception. Otherwise, it just corrupts data.

Answer (score 2):

The .NET library has a thread safe dictionary, the `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx

Updated: I didn't exactly answer the question, so here's updated with more answery to exact question posed.
As per the MSDN:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

> A Dictionary can support multiple readers concurrently,
>   as long as the collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating
>   through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In
>   the rare case where an enumeration contends with write accesses, the
>   collection must be locked during the entire enumeration. To allow the
>   collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing,
>   you must implement your own synchronization.
>
> For a thread-safe alternative, see ConcurrentDictionary.
>
> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread
>   safe.

Comment: This is dangerously misleading. Even when replacing the dictionary in OP’s code with the `ConcurrentDictionary`, the code would *still* be unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

You've just been lucky so far. It's not thread-safe.

From [the `Dictionary<K,V>` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)...

> A `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` can support multiple readers
>   concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified. Even so,
>   enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe
>   procedure. In the rare case where an enumeration contends with write
>   accesses, the collection must be locked during the entire enumeration.
>   To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading
>   and writing, you must implement your own synchronization.