# contents of dictionary class vanishing, possible thread issue?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, dictionary

Forgive me but I'm not quite sure where in my code things are going wrong!
I'm working on creating a multithreaded tcp server, and am attempting to store strings using a dictionary. The code looks like this:

```
class Echo : Iprotocol
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    private const int BUFFSIZE = 32; //buffer size

    private Socket client_sock; //Socket
    private Ilogger logger; // logger

    public Echo(Socket sock, Ilogger log)
    {
        this.client_sock = sock;
        this.logger = log;
    }
    public string handlewhois(string inname)
    {
        ArrayList entry = new ArrayList();
        string name = inname;
        string message = null;
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(name) == true)
        {
            entry.Add(System.DateTime.Now + "Dictionary reference found at thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode());
            message = dictionary[name];
        }
        else
        {
            entry.Add(System.DateTime.Now + "Dictionary reference not found at thread:  " + Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode());
            message = "ERROR: no entries found";
        }
        logger.writeEntry(entry);
        return message;
    }
    public string handlewhois(string inname, string inlocation)
    {
        ArrayList entry = new ArrayList();
        string name = inname;
        string location = inlocation;
        string message = null;
        entry.Add(System.DateTime.Now + "Dictionary reference created or updated at thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode());
        dictionary.Add(name, location);
        message = "OK";
        logger.writeEntry(entry);
        return message;
    }
}
```

It runs perfectly fine, however as I step through it in debug, I see the the dictionary entry created, however when it gets to the line: 
logger.writeEntry(entry);

It suddenly vanishes, with dictionary not containing any values.

I think it may have something to do with the multithreading but honestly I have no idea!

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary is not thread safe - please consider using [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) instead.

From the [Dictionary documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> A Dictionary can support multiple readers concurrently,
>   as long as the collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating
>   through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In
>   the rare case where an enumeration contends with write accesses, the
>   collection must be locked during the entire enumeration. To allow the
>   collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing,
>   you must implement your own synchronization.
>
> For a thread-safe alternative, see ConcurrentDictionary.
>
> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread
>   safe.

See [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7246005/1220971) for more information.